# Why is this XS code that returns a PerlIO* leaky?

Tags: perl, xs, perl-io

I am trying to write some XS code that exposes pieces a library to
Perl code as a stream interface that can be written to. The
`get_stream` function below is supposed to be a constructor that
prepares and returns a PerlIO object. I figured that I only need the
`Write` and `Close` methods, so I left all other function slots blank.

```
typedef struct {
    struct _PerlIO base;
    mylib_context* ctx;
} PerlIOmylib;

/* [...] */

PERLIO_FUNCS_DECL(PerlIO_mylib_funcs) = {
.fsize = sizeof(PerlIO_funcs),
.name  = "mylib",
.size  = sizeof(PerlIOmylib,
.Write = mylib_write,
.Close = mylib_close,
};

/* XS below */

PerlIO*
get_stream (SV* context_obj)
CODE:
mylib_context* ctx = (mylib_context*) SvIV (SvRV (context_obj));
PerlIO* f = PerlIO_allocate (aTHX);
f = PerlIO_push (aTHX, f, PERLIO_FUNCS_CAST(&PerlIO_mylib_funcs), "a", NULL);
PerlIOSelf(f, PerlIOmylib)->ctx = ctx;
PerlIOBase(f)->flags |= PERLIO_F_OPEN;
RETVAL = f;
OUTPUT:
RETVAL
```

When I use the provided interface like this...

```
{
    my $fh = MyLib::get_stream($lib_ctx);
    print $fh "x" x 300;
}
```

... the `mylib_write` function gets called, so I haven't totally
screwed up so far. (I verified this by inserting debug printf
statements.) However, I would like the PerlIO object to be closed when
`$fh` goes out of scope, just the way things work with regular
filehandles created by `open`. But at the moment, the `mylib_close`
function is only called during interpreter shutdown.

Directly calling `close` works fine, setting `$fh` to `undef` does
not.

**UPDATE:** Following ikegami's advice, I used `Devel::Peek::Dump` and `sv_dump`
and found out that the handle returned `get_stream` function is a "RV"
which points to a `SV = PVGV(...)`. The glob (`PVGV`) has its
reference counter set to 3 which doesn't seem right.

I added

```
CLEANUP:
SvREFCNT_dec (SvRV (ST(0)));
SvREFCNT_dec (SvRV (ST(0)));
```

which cures the symptom: The `close` function is called when `$fh`
goes out of scope at the end of the block. But I still don't quite
understand the underlying problem.

This is the C code generated for the `OUTPUT` section:

```
ST(0) = sv_newmortal();
{
    GV *gv = newGVgen("MyLib");
    if (do_open(gv, "+<&", 3, FALSE, 0, 0, RETVAL) )
        sv_setsv(ST(0), sv_bless(newRV((SV*)gv), gv_stashpv("MyLib",1)));
    else
        ST(0) = &PL_sv_undef;
}
XSRETURN(1);
```

How does the GV's reference count end up at 3?

Comment: ug, whole new question in same in same post?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `close` is called at global destruction, that means your handle still exists at global destruction. You're leaking!

In C/XS code, you can use `sv_dump(sv)` to dump a scalar to stderr. In Perl code, you can  use [Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Peek)'s `Dump` to get the same functionality. This will show you reference counts.

---

In answer to your new question,

You have three allocation, but only one deallocation (the delayed one from sv_2mortal).

- `gv`: Pointer always discarded. Memory leak!

  You could either decrement the refcnt of `gv` on error, or you decrement the refcnt on unconditionally after using `newRV_inc` to "transfer ownership" to the RV when open succeeds.
- SV from `newRV`: Pointer always discarded. Memory leak!

  Why not just return it instead of copying it? Just mark it as mortal to cause Perl to decrement its refcnt after the caller gets it.

Fixed:

```
{
    GV *gv = newGVgen("MyLib");
    if (!do_open(gv, "+<&", 3, FALSE, 0, 0, RETVAL) ) {
        SvREFCNT_dec(gv);
        XSRETURN_UNDEF;
    }

    ST(0) = sv_2mortal(sv_bless(newRV_noinc((SV*)gv), gv_stashpv("MyLib",1))));
    XSRETURN(1);
}
```

Comment: When I add `Pushed` and `Popped` functions, I see that `Popped` is still only called during global interpreter shutdown.

Comment: I previously missed that `close` was called then too. (I thought you said it wasn't being called at all.) Your file handle is surviving until global destruction. You're leaking.

Comment: Putting `sv_dump (ST(0))` into a `CLEANUP` section revealed that the reference count of the "thing" that the `PerlIO *` was turned into was 3. Reducing that by 2 causes `close` to be called at the rigth time, but I am still confused.

Comment: Added answer to new question.

Comment: The C code in question was generated by `ExtUtils::ParseXS`, presumably based on the return type  `(PerlIO *)`. So... is the generator buggy?

Answer (score 0):

I just reproduced the issue with a trivial example:

```
$ h2xs -n foo
Defaulting to backwards compatibility with perl 5.14.2
If you intend this module to be compatible with earlier perl versions, please
specify a minimum perl version with the -b option.

Writing foo/ppport.h
Writing foo/lib/foo.pm
Writing foo/foo.xs
Writing foo/fallback/const-c.inc
Writing foo/fallback/const-xs.inc
Writing foo/Makefile.PL
Writing foo/README
Writing foo/t/foo.t
Writing foo/Changes
Writing foo/MANIFEST
```

To `foo/foo.xs`, I added:

```
PerlIO*
get_stream(char* name);
CODE:
RETVAL = PerlIO_open (name, "w");
OUTPUT:
RETVAL
```

and the following trivial test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use foo;
use Devel::Peek;
{
    my $fh = foo::get_stream ("testfile");
    Devel::Peek::Dump $fh;
    print $fh "hello\n";
}
print "bye\n";
```

Sure enough, the reference count of the generated glob is set to 3,
and `strace` reveals that closing the file descriptor is the last
thing that the Perl interpreter does.

So, `PerlIO*` handling seems to be leaky by default. :-(

The following `typemap` snippet seems to fix this (thanks, ikegami!):

```
TYPEMAP
PerlIO *    T_PIO
OUTPUT
T_PIO
    {
        GV *gv = newGVgen("$Package");
        if (do_open(gv, "+<&", 3, FALSE, 0, 0, $var) ) {
            $arg = sv_2mortal(sv_bless(newRV_noinc((SV*)gv), gv_stashpv("$Package",1)));
        } else {
            SvREFCNT_dec(gv);
            $arg = &PL_sv_undef;
        }
    }
```